# Parsing Google's search results

Tags: perl, data-mining, google-search-api

I'm "working" on a data mining project and I've chosen to parse Google search results. Now before I actually start, I want to consult you - experienced folks. 
I did a bit of research on how Google delivers results and I analyzed structure of a result page. That's all alright, I've already figured out regexes and data structures I'll use.

In between I encountered their *CAPTCHA* because I was searching too fast; oh, the irony. I've also discovered that *they* limit results to 1000 actually. Now, is there any way I could avoid those peripeties, perhaps slowing the rate of *url* fetching to solve the first one or reporting when encountering *CAPTCHA* so that it waits for my input; that might do it, but what about the other one ? Does Google provide some kind of an API that I can use for a workaround? I couldn't find one on their code.* page.

Comment: Persist and they will block your ip address.  Use their API (and pay, if necessary).

Comment: Mining data from a company that mines data?

Comment: @Caterham I know it's silly but I have to do it. 
@ysth I'm not paying for results, I'll try with other search engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always look on CPAN first!

[https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Google](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST%3a%3aGoogle)

If someone hasn't already solved your problem, chances are it's a weird one :-)

Answer (score 9):

There is a [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).

It returns results in json or XML, so you won't even need to use regexes. However, you do need to pay for more than 100 searches a day.

What exactly are you trying to do?  Maybe there is a better way to accomplish it.